# Existence of a joint distribution given the conditional and marginal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, conditional-probability

Can anyone point me a book where it has a proof of Theorem 1.7 (ii) of Jun Shao's book - Mathematical Statistics? I need this to show that given a distribution on one space and a collection of conditional distributions (which are conditioned on values of the first space) on another space, I can construct a joint distribution in the product space.
There is a print of the theorem below.
[image]

Comment: It seems to be a direct application of [Carathéodory's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem).

Comment: I don't think so. I'm looking for a result that guarantees the existence of the joint distribution, since I have a conditional and marginal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I found the result that I needed. The theorem with the necessary proof is in the book: "Measure, Integration and Probability" from Burril, pages 397 - 399. (T.15-3C and T.15-3D)